# Redirect Image urls to another domain htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a wordpress instance and I all my images are loaded from eg:

https://site1/wp-content/uploads/image.png. 
Is there a way to load these images from
 https://site2/wp-content/uploads/image.png using htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

You can with `mod_rewrite` enabled. This ought to work with apache

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(.+)$  https://site2/wp-content/uploads/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks. I already tried this. It doesn't have ane effect though

Comment: oh? I actually tested it with two of my servers (not Wordpress though)  with success... maybe part of the path doesn't match?

Comment: I cannot be sure because the path still remains the same. It's like the htaccess file is not working. Probably something on my end. Thanks for the code. Once I fix this issue I will try it

Comment: Be aware that if you are on an nginx or something else this is not viable.